# "Runtime error event loop already running" during asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, proxybroker

I am trying out some asyncio examples found on the web: 
[Proxybroker example](https://proxybroker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#proxybroker-examples-grab)

When I run this first example:

```
"""Find and show 10 working HTTP(S) proxies."""

import asyncio
from proxybroker import Broker

async def show(proxies):
    while True:
        proxy = await proxies.get()
        if proxy is None: break
        print('Found proxy: %s' % proxy)

proxies = asyncio.Queue()
broker = Broker(proxies)
tasks = asyncio.gather(
    broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
    show(proxies))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

But the loop completes as expected. 
I'm new to concurrent code so any explanation / pseudo code of what is occurring would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install this package,and run it passed, no error occured,are use a ide? try to run it on cli,or move it another directory

Comment: Yep I was running in notebook.